# Setting up a web testing environment

Tags: testing

We have a need to set up a testing environment to test our pages output.  I'm reluctant to use Selenium, because we just don't have the hardware to do it.  I'm also more concerned with whether there is content on the page, than whether the page "looks" right.

From that, I'm looking to set up something command-line, that we can pass in a URL, a list of requirements, and have it respond back true/false, etc.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I might be able to go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write something command line, you have everything you need in the System.Net namespace.  You can create HttpRequests with Get/Post and then inspect the response for what you are expecting to see.

One technique I've heard Jimmy Bogard talk about is adding metadata to tables/Divs that help in verification of the data you expect.

There's more info here:

http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/10/22/c4mvc-ui-testing-screencast-posted.aspx